# Minecraft Multiplayer Block Placing Issue

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play Minecraft 1.5_01 and I have my own server. During multiplayer, whenever I try to place a block, it disappears about 3 seconds later. When I destroy one, it reappears after about 3 seconds.

Also, I can't use crafting tables, furnaces, chests, dispensers, or beds.

Can someone help me?

Comment: That sounds like textbook latency issues (lag).  I think you'll find you're virtually unable to place paintings, signs, boats, and minecarts as well.

Comment: Sometimes this happens to me, and it's almost always due to poor internet connection. Try disconnecting/reconnecting to the internet, restarting the server, or just waiting a while.

Comment: nothing works!!

Comment: Also, try restarting your server. My second-worst lag experience was fixed instantly with a server restart.

Comment: I've done that many times already.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem solved itself somehow.

Comment: That's...really not helpful to anyone except you.

Answer (score 17):

Have you moved away from your spawn point? The area around the spawn point can only be altered by administrator ("op") players. Either move away from spawn (about 20 or 30 blocks), give yourself op, or disable spawn-protection by adding `spawn-protection=0` to your server.properties file.

If you *have* done any of these, then your connection to the server is bad and you're experiencing desynchronisation between the server and client. The problem then is either your server acting up (is it modded?), or with your network connection / the network code at the operating system level and not Minecraft. Make sure your JVM is up-to-date at the very least, as I've experienced multiple minutes of lag loading chunks and opening containers when running the latest Minecraft on an outdated JVM on Windows.

If it's your server acting up, try restarting it. If you're running a modded server, make sure you're using the most recent stable version to avoid bugs that could cause an unstable connection.

Comment: what is JVM? :/ And I use mac.

Comment: @user9090 Java Virtual Machine. java.com

Comment: @9090 If you're on a mac, Java is updated by Apple. To check if you have an update waiting (which, if so, would probably be why Minecraft is behaving badly): choose the Apple menu at top-left → "Software Update…". If you need to update your JVM, there will be an item in the Software Update app named something similar to "Java update".

Comment: there's no update there

Comment: @user9090: For Macs, the Java version is tied to the version of OS X. If you need a newer version, you'll have to upgrade your OS (Yes, this is crazy. Also, true. =P)

Comment: @Satanicpuppy I think i have the newest version (10.6.7)

Comment: @9090 My system is up-to-date (both OS and JVM) and my version of Java is "Java SE 6 1.6.0_24-b07-334". You can check what you've got by running **Java Preferences**.app, located in `/Applications/Utilities`.

Comment: @user9090: Then your Java should be fine. If it's version 1.6.0_24, some people have complained of issues. (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2797741?start=0&tstart=0) So that could be your problem...

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have the same.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy i do have 1.6.0_24. How do I downgrade?

Comment: @9090 I remembered another potential desync cause: server instability. Try restarting your server before you get into the tangles of trying to downgrade Java.

Comment: Edited the answer to mention server restarts, as well as modded server bugs.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yeah, i restarted and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @9090 Is your server local (on the same machine as the client) or remote (on the internet)? How much latency is there on your connection to your server? If you open a Terminal.app window and type `ping [your-server-ip-goes-here]`, let it run for a bit, and then stop it with Ctrl-c, how many ms does it report for the min/avg/max round trip?

Comment: it's local. if latency is lag, not that much. it says 2.108/14.026/94.427/22.961ms. It was more ms at the beginning, then it was constant for a while, and then it started spiking.

Comment: @9090 That looks right for a local server, but spikes are worrisome. How big are the spikes? If very large, that would indicate that there's a problem affected the local fake-network connection the client and server are using.

Comment: 2-2-2-2-2-2-2-3-2-2-4-5-2-2-2-18-2-2-21-2-2-73-94-16-4-33-77-2-40-8-39-2-3(in ms) This is about the log it gave me.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie how large are very large spikes?

Comment: @9090 Those don't seem like very large spikes to me (in fact, those spikes are great latencies for a remote server), but the fact that it's spiking at all may indicate problems. Or might not. This depth of networking stuff brings us to the limit of my troubleshooting abilities.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie So what do I do?

Comment: @9090 Pray for a more knowledgeable SE user to answer. Or try random things, like rebooting the machine, reinstalling Minecraft and/or the server, downgrading Java, etc… Sorry I couldn't be more helpful!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ok, but could you at least tell me how to downgrade Java?

Comment: @9090 I'm afraid that's beyond my abilities. You could try asking at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Were you sneaking when it happened? This occurs all the time on my Minecraft server and the only solution I have found is to place or destroy blocks while standing.

Comment: No, this happens all the time. I can never place blocks.